# PHP / Javascript: History.go(-1) not working, browser back DOES

Tags: javascript, php

I changed something between last night and this morning and now my back buttons are not working.

I have used

```
<button type="submit" onClick="history.go(-1)">Back</button>
```

without a problem up until this morning. Now, when this button is clicked, the previous URL is loaded, but my PHP $_SESSION is not, cause me to be redirected to my login page.

If I use the browsers built-in back button, it loads without any problems.

> This problem persists in both FireFox 38.0.5 and IE 11.

I have tried `history.go(-1)`, `history.back` and a few others and there is something wrong with the JS.

Any ideas what to look out for? I am by no means a JS expert (this is about as much as I do) and my site has virtually no JS in it to begin with.

I'd love to give more code examples, but as I haven't the faintest idea where the problem is, I would only be able to upload my entire system...

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you want to use `type="submit"` don't use `<button>` but `<input>`

Comment: If you go back, you don't have to submit your form, so only use `<button>` or `<input type="button" />`

Comment: @Hearner `<button type="submit"` is perfectly valid, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Vhortex and Hearner!!!

I had accidentally made it `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`. So my code should be 
`<button type="submit" onClick="history.go(-1)">Back</button>`

Is there any way to delete a post? This is embarrassing...(kidding)

Happy Thursday!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing your form submit to go back 1 page before the actual "login form". Before submit fires and send data to your PHP form in the server, the browser already loaded 1 page back.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick="window.history.go(-1);">Back</button>
```

YOu have many problems in you code : If you want to use `type="submit"` you can't use `<button>` but `<input>` like

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="window.history.go(-1);" />
```

Or `<button onClick="window.history.go(-1);">Back</button>`

The fisrt one is better

Comment: In what is the first one better?

Comment: `<button> </button>` causes problems sometimes with IE